# Prove the central limit theorem with a sum when n increases

Tags: r, statistics, montecarlo

I'm trying to use Monte Carlo simulation in order to show how the sum of an uniform sample is normal distributed when the dimension of the sample increase.

More precisely: let define $X ~ U[2,3]$ where $X_1,...,X_n$ is an iid sample from X and $S = \sum_{1}^{n}(X_i). I want use Monte Carlo Simulation in order to show that the distribution of S is approximately normal when n is large (as predicted by Central Limit Theorem).

What I want to show is that when the number of observation in S rise its distribution is more normal.
Is also important that I'm talking about the **sum** of $X_i$, so I'm not considering the general case with the mean.

The problem is that I can obtain a more (or less) normal distribution when I increase (or decrease) the number of time in the Monte Carlo. instead, If I change the sample dimension the differences are VERY low, I can see a normal distribution even when the sample is 10 and, for example, from 10 to 100 i can't notice any significant difference.

Here there is my MWE:

```
    #create random variable with sample size of 1000 that is uniformally distributed
    data <- runif(n=10000, min=2, max=3)
    hist(data, col='steelblue', main='Histogram from the Uniform')

    #I take, for 1000 times, the sum of a sample=10 from X
    sample10 <- c()
    n = 1000
    for (i in 1:n){
     sample10[i] = sum(sample(data, 10, replace=TRUE))
    }
    hist(sample10, col ='steelblue', main='Sample size = 10', prob=TRUE)
    qqnorm(sample10); qqline(sample10)


    #Increasing the sample dimension
    sample100 <- c()
    n = 1000
    for (i in 1:n){
     sample100[i] = sum(sample(data, 100, replace=TRUE))
    }
    hist(sample100, col ='steelblue', main='Sample size = 100', prob=TRUE)
    qqnorm(sample100); qqline(sample100)
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. Sorry for my English, any request for clarification is welcome.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem in what you did.  Adding 10 uniforms together gives a distribution that is very close to normal.  You'll only see obvious differences if you make the sample very small, e.g. 2 will be obvious, 3 is probably noticeable, but 4 or more is going to be hard to spot in a histogram or QQ plot.

Comment: Ok Thanks! but why with the mean differences are more evident?

Comment: If you use the mean instead of the sum, the only difference will be the location and scale of the result.  I wouldn't expect any difference in shape.  BTW, if you want to see slower convergence, use a skewed distribution as input (e.g. exponential instead of uniform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simulation of the sums of `n` random uniforms U(2, 3) with `n` varying from 1 to 11 by steps of 2. Each sum is replicated 1000 times.

```r
set.seed(2022)

nvec <- seq(1, 12, by = 2)
R <- 1e3
S_list <- lapply(nvec, \(n) {
  replicate(R, sum(runif(n, 2, 3)))
})
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now the histograms. You will see that convergence is very quick. That feature is even the basis of a CLT-based [pseudo-RNG algorithm for the standard normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Approximating_a_Normal_distribution).

```r
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
mapply(\(S, n) {
  main <- sprintf("S with n = %d", n)
  hist(S, main = main, freq = FALSE)
  invisible(NULL)
}, S_list, nvec)
```

[image]

```
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> NULL
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Don't worry about these `NULL`'s, they are the return value of `mapply`.

And the QQ-plots.

```r
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
mapply(\(S, n) {
  main <- sprintf("S with n = %d", n)
  qqnorm(S, main = main)
  qqline(S)
}, S_list, nvec)
```

[image]

```
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> NULL
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! what is the meaning of "R <- 1e3
S_list <- lapply(nvec, \(n) " and also the one for mapply?

Comment: @RobertCGA If you want the Monte Carlo simulation of `sum(U)`, you will have to run the same code many times, `R` is the number of times it is run (this is what I mean with *"Each sum is replicated 1000 times"*). I have simulated `R` times for increasing sample sizes, `lapply` loops over a vector of those sample sizes and outputs a list of vectors, the sums `S`. As for `mapply`, it loops over both the results list `S_list` and the vector of sizes `nvec`. The only reason why I use `mapply` and not `lapply` or even a `for` loop is to have the plots titles display the sample sizes `n`.

Comment: Ok thanks. And there is a reson why you call the sum "S"? is this a name variable or an abreviation of "sum"? last, this slash stand for? \(S, n) {

Comment: @RobertCGA You call the simulations' results `sample10` and `sample100`. I called it `S_list` and `S` because they are sums and because `sample` already is a base R function. As for the slash, its the new lambda functions introduced in R 4.1, it's a notation for anonymous functions, `function(S, n)` or `\(S, n)` are equivalent.